# Read Nutch crawled data from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, nutch

I wrote a program to store nutch(2.1) crawled results in MySQL. It works fine. I get the file formats specified for search. I get few `jpeg` file. I want to fetch these images from DB(I am not sure if they are getting stored). I have a field with image URL. I can go and fetch it from there. But then what is the use of nutch storing so much data in MySQL.  Can you help me with that. 
I am using following code :

```
    String crawlArg = "urls  -threads 5";

    // Run Crawl tool

     try {
             ToolRunner.run(NutchConfiguration.create(), new org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler(),
                             tokenize(crawlArg));
     } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return;
     }
```

Please ask any more details that you might need. I am novice in nutch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the content field in `MySQL` which is `LongBlob` and stores the image.

Comment: Could you suggest me a good tutorial to read the crawled pages using java.

Comment: What  i am asking is i need to read the crawleddb using java code

Comment: @muthu :Use this http://nlp.solutions.asia/?p=180 . This give precise information.